# Beautifulsoup4 Import Error: No module named bs4

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup, pip

I'm creating a Flask web application and I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup for some html parsing. I have a virtual environment in my application's folder.

When I install bs4 I first activate my virtual environment using `source venv/bin/activate`.
Then I use `pip install beautifulsoup4`. The package does successfully install to my site-packages folder, I can see the package and the permissions on everything are fine. I can uninstall the package with pip and reinstall just fine.

In one of my files I have this line at the top `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. Which always results in the error: ImportError: No module named bs4.

I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the Flask app is running out of that venv? Can you add `import sys; print(sys.path)` before the `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and make sure that it includes the site-packages that you successfully installed to?

Comment: Hmm no it's not...how can I fix that?

Comment: Ugh thanks so much!! I just had to add `activate_this = '/path/to/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))` at the top of my WSGI file and everything works great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not running Flask from the virtual environment. So, of course, anything you've installed in that virtual environment isn't available.

Since you haven't told us *how* you're running Flask, it's hard to tell you exactly what you're doing wrong.

However, if you read the [Deployment Options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/) section in the docs, they explain how to use virtual environments. For example, if you're using Apache with mod_wsgi, you add these lines to the top of your `.wsgi` file:

```
activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

The basic idea is similar for other ways of running your server (except for deployment options that have built-in support for venvs, where it's trivial, or pure-Python servers, where you can just run the server out of the same venv as Flask).

---

Alternatively, if you're happy to install Flask system-wide and run your server out of your default system environment, you could just install beautifulsoup4 system-wide too…

Comment: Oh man I actually just figured it our before you posted this haha, but thanks again for the explanation. This is my first time using Flask so I kinda dove in without understand exactly what was happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @PaulD'Amora: This is really more about how `mod_wsgi` (or whatever WSGI container you're using) works than about Flask. Which is good news, because it means that if you ever switch from Flask to a different WSGI framework, the knowledge will transfer. :)